# What is the best way to instantiate a 172820 String Array in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a text file of words or Strings there is 172820 lines and each line is to be one word or element.  What is the best way to instantiate the array.  I will have to parse the array as well.  For example I need to be able to see which words starts with the letter 'z' or 'a' etc...  I need to instantiate a large array and be able to parse it.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way, given that you need to search your strings, and given that there are quite many of them, is probably to store these words in database, and use SQL queries to find the ones you're looking for.

Comment: Then cache into memory the most commonly used ones, or have a nice loading screen while you go off to your DB :-)

Comment: JB Nizet would I be able to do my own queries my getting each word from the DB and checking if it meets specified guidelines or will this lead to inefficiency and cause the app to lag?

Comment: The app will likely "lag" while you are inserting and parsing all those rows.  But after the db's all setup it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Eric, my app requires me to repeatedly parse the DB will this be a major problem or only cause a couple seconds "lag" each time I parse the DB??